# What does "être de la gueule" mean?

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

I came across this sentence:

> Alors j'ai senti que j'étais vide, que mon énergie **était de la
> gueule** et qu'au fond de moi-même il n'y avait rien (...).
>
> *Céline, Casse-pipe (« Carnet du cuirassier Destouches ») (Gallimard, 1970) p. 112.*

What does "**être de la gueule**" mean in this case? I looked it up in the dictionary, but the definition of "*avoir de la gueule*" as "*avoir quelque chose qui retient l'attention; être bien fait; avoir du chic*" didn't quite seem to fit the context of the sentence previously quoted. Well, you got any idea?

Answer (score 5):

The underlying expression are *[être [que] de la]/[avoir que d'la] [la gueule](https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/dictionary/definition/gueule#11)*, literally "To be loudmouth / to have only loudmouth". Another link for *que de la gueule* [here](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/76423).

The meaning is:

> [The act of] someone who speak and brag a lot but who chicken out when confronted to reality, i.e. someone who have "no balls."

In the quoted text, the meaning is something like *my energy was phony*.

This is very different to the expression *avoir de la gueule* which is positive and states something (and more rarely [someone](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/il-de-la-gueule-lo%C3%AFck-peyron-santhi-v%C3%A9loupoul%C3%A9/?originalSubdomain=fr)) is strong, nice, impressive.

Answer (score 1):

Cela veut dire que son énergie était une apparence sans réalité,  une impression fausse d'avoir de l'énergie qu'il/elle croyait se trouver, mais qui était le résultat du fait qu'il/elle se  leurrait à le croire  ou bien le résultat de [faux-semblant](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faux-semblant) plus ou moins inconscient ; le fait que cela est soudainement ressenti semble signifier que l'affectation ne serait pas entièrement calculée et consciente.

Ne pas oublier qu' « avoir de la gueule » en parlant d'une personne, en français grossier, signifie aussi avoir une attitude dans laquelle on reconnait de la force, de l'allant, de l'autorité, mais tout cela montré  d'une façon plutôt criarde,  caractéristique de manières et de sentiments peu raffinés.

Comment: *Avoir de la gueule* n'est pas du français grossier mais du français familier. C'est rarement employé pour une personne mais quand ça l'est, le sens n'est pas vraiment ce que tu décris, c'est rarement péjoratif. Pour que ce le soit, il faut ajouter *que*.

Comment: @jlliagre Non, « que » n'est pas nécessaire ;  Voilà ce qu'on peut entendre : « T'as trop de gueule ! C'est pour ça qui t'aime pas. »,  « C'ui-là, il a de la gueule et c'est pour ça qu'on l'écoute. », « Y t'as une de ces gueule ! Y'a'q lui qui connait. ». De plus, je n'ai jamais entendu cet argot dans la bouche de personnes éduquées. Plus généralement, ce n'est pas un hazard si on trouve le mot « amuse-gueule » dans le TLFi et pas du tout le mot «  amuse-bouche », que depuis 2000 certains Français ont trouvé un bien meilleur terme et utilisent de plus en plus à la place  ; (1/3)

Comment: @jlliagre du terme à consonnances argotiques ; la raison est évidente, le mot « gueule » dans ces contextes pu l'argot, et en bon français  le terme « gueule » est utilisé essentiellement  pour désigner la bouche des animaux carnassiers, des reptiles, des poissons et  batraciens. Cela montre bien  que ces combinaisons donnent une impression de grossièreté. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amuse-gueule%2Camuse-bouche&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Camuse%20-%20gueule%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camuse%20-%20bouche%3B%2Cc0 (2/3)

Comment: @jlliagre https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amuse+gueule%2Camuse+bouche&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Camuse%20gueule%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camuse%20bouche%3B%2Cc0 (3/3)

Comment: [**Bataille !**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amuse+gueule%2Camuse+bouche%2C%C3%A7a+a+de+la+gueule&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3)  **:-)**

Comment: @jlliagre On peut inférer que pour cette expression (avoir de la gueule) il existe tout d'abord, en comparaison avec « amuse-gueule » un vide lexical et qu'ensuite l'idée de « bouche », si peut-être connecté de loin à travers le mot « gout », n'a pas grand chose à faire avec l'idée d'apparence qui est l'idée principale. La place indisputée n'est pas nécessairement une confirmation que personne ne ressente quelque chose qui n'est pas tout à fait comme il faut.

Comment: 1: Est-ce que tu penses que les personnes éduquées ne disent jamais de grossièretés ? 2: Est-ce que tu te rends compte que dire que quelqu'un n'est pas éduqué parce qu'il dit *avoir de la gueule* peut être mal perçu par ledit quelqu'un ?

Comment: @jlliagre Une chose est sûre, de nos jours, elles en disent de plus en plus en public  ; ça  laisse souvent  peu de  doute sur le comportement en privé. Bien sûr, ça va être mal perçu, mais je ne vais pas si loin et je dirais certainement plutôt quelque chose comme « malgré une éducation au dessus de la moyenne etc. » ; de toute façon, comme l'a dit un certain psychologue américain, il n'est pas (j'ajoute « toujours ») possible de dire quelque chose de valeur sans marcher sur les pieds à quelqu'un.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126543/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-what-does-etre-de-la-gueule-mean).

Answer (score 1):

> Que de fois je suis remonté du pansage et tout seul sur mon lit, pris
> d’un immense désespoir, j’ai malgré mes dix-sept ans pleuré comme une
> première communiante. Alors j’ai senti que j’étais vide, que mon
> énergie était **de la gueule** et qu’au fond de moi-même il n’y avait
> rien, que je n’étais pas un homme - je m’étais trop longtemps cru tel,
> peut-être beaucoup comme moi avant l’âge, peut-être beaucoup le
> croient encore quoique plus vieux, et en de mêmes circonstances
> sentiraient aussi leurs cœurs partir à la dérive comme une bouteille à
> la mer, ballotté par la vague les injures et la croyance que cela ne
> finira jamais - alors là vraiment j’ai souffert aussi bien du mal
> présent que de mon infériorité virile et de la constater. J’ai senti
> que les grands discours que je tenais un mois plus tôt sur **l’énergie
> juvénile n’étaient que fanfaronnade** et qu’au pied du mur je n’étais
> qu’un malheureux transplanté ayant perdu la moitié de ses facultés et
> ne se servant de celles qui restent que pour constater le néant de
> cette énergie. (…) Au fond de moi-même je cache un fond d’orgueil qui
> me fait peur à moi-même, je veux dominer non par un pouvoir factice
> comme l’ascendance militaire mais je veux plus tard ou le plus tôt
> possible être un homme complet, le serai-je jamais, aurai-je la
> fortune nécessaire pour avoir cette facilité d’agir qui vous permet de
> vous éduquer.
>
> [ Céline, [*Casse-pipe*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casse-pipe) (« Carnet du cuirassier Destouches »)
> (Gallimard, 1970) à la page 112, je
> souligne. ]

---

Du sens de « bouche humaine » de *gueule* vient un sens extensif, populaire, pour « visage, figure » au 16-17<sup>e</sup> s. avec des emplois non péjoratifs comme *belle gueule* etc. ; début 20<sup>e</sup> on a l'extension « forme, aspect (d'un objet) », comme dans *avoir de la gueule*<sup>1</sup>, « de l'allure » (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. A. Rey, Robert). [Ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/46618) on a présenté d'autres emplois familiers ; on se souvient par exemple de *fine gueule*<sup>2</sup>, pour le gourmet.

En ajoutant le contexte et l'emploi de *fanfaronnade* plus loin dans le texte, je lis ça comme « de la [frime](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/frime) » ou quelque chose de *superficiel*, une *apparence extérieure*, le « visage » voire la « bonne figure » d'une chose/personne, surtout quand c'est opposé à son « fond ».

Mais à mon avis il n'y aurait ni locution ni d'ellipse de la particule *ne* ou de *que*, mais simplement *un sens étendu* et familier du mot *gueule*, ce qui s'analyserait comme un attribut de l'*énergie*, voire son origine ou type. En effet, je peux percevoir aussi la formulation comme créant l'origine (en provenance de... la *gueule*, par opposition au... *ventre* ?). J'ai aussi trouvé dans une [traduction](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&redir_esc=y&id=BHwbAQAAIAAJ&dq=c%C3%A9line%20cannon%20fodder&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=empty) et ce n'est pas du tout déterminant mais ça influence certainement ma réflexion « [...] that what I took for energy was only my big mouth [...] » même si Céline n'avait pas employé le possessif.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> De registre **familier** ([Robert en ligne](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/gueule), [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/gueule/38539#179906), [L'OBS](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/definition/avoir_de_la_gueule.php)), ou *populaire* [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_de_la_gueule) ; [Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9G1685) non marqué pour des objets parmi des emplois qui le sont ; voir aussi [Wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/avoir%20de%20la%20gueule). Exemple : "Tandis que si vous annoncez « le général de Lèchefrite, ancien ambassadeur », ou le « marquis de la Lèchefrite, officier d'académie », ça vous a de la gueule !... Pas, Mélanie ?" (Guy de Téramond, « La Petite Maud » au Wiktionnaire).</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Découlant essentiellement du sens de *bouche* pour *gourmandise* puis par métonymie le *gourmand*, à la fin du 19<sup>e</sup> (DHLF) : « Aussi fine gueule qu’Huysmans, Mirbeau considérait celui-ci comme un vieil enfant quinteux, petit-bourgeois et perdu dans son miroton et le Syllabus. » L. [Daudet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9on_Daudet) (au Wiktionnaire à [*fine gueule*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fine_gueule)).</sub>