# Expression "avoir de la gueule"

Tags: expressions, usage

It seems to mean to look good/nice/attractive. *Avoir de la gueule*?

Can you use it for places and people

E.g.

1. *Nice a l'air d'avoir de la gueule.*
2. *Sophie a de la gueule*, as in she is attractive or looks good at this moment in an outfit or something?

Comment: Please do not use it much, it is very familiar and not elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more used with objects, for example cars, houses...

*Avoir l'air d'avoir de la gueule* is also too convoluted. What you would say is:

> *Nice est une ville qui a de la gueule.*

> *Il faut dire qu'elle a de la gueule avec ses maisons aux pignons à volutes et ses arcades au rez-de-chaussée des habitations.* (Blog [Referring to a square in Arras](http://paris-butteauxcailles.eklablog.com/balade-a-arras-a208791992))

It is very rarely used with persons but you might say:

> *Sophie a de la gueule avec sa nouvelle tenue !*

A real life example:

> *Il a de la gueule, Loïck Peyron*, [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/il-de-la-gueule-lo%C3%AFck-peyron-santhi-v%C3%A9loupoul%C3%A9/?originalSubdomain=fr)

*Avoir de la gueule* shouldn't be confused with *[être de la gueule](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46615/what-does-%C3%AAtre-de-la-gueule-mean/46635#46635)*.